# Flutter smoothly scaling app bars title on scroll

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

for now I have mock of view as presented. I want this app bars title to be twice as big when I'm on the top of the screen with no buttons, and scale smoothly back to current form with two buttons when I scroll down. I tried to experiment with sliverappbar but without effect. I use here scaffold with standard app bar. Is there a convenient way to achieve it, or I have to write it myself. I'd be thankful for any advice.

EDIT: Something like showed here [gif](https://miro.medium.com/max/370/1*fG1rLB-EPGZVlz22DCSNVA.gif)

[image]

Comment: Can you share a gif of that?

Comment: @Diwyansh I've added a gif

Comment: Okay, Basically you have to use SliverAppBar for  this animation. You can try and I'll also share a reference code for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try again although I've already did with slivers

Comment: Okay then I will share, just allot me some time

Comment: Sure, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hey @Diwyansh How it's going?

Comment: Hi. please check the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **CustomScrollView** with **Slivers** to achieve your desired result. I'm sharing an `example` for this you can `customize` it as per your need.

```
 CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          expandedHeight: 120,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: Text("Barb's Latest",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),),titlePadding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
          ),automaticallyImplyLeading: true,
        ),
        SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) => Container(
                      height: 100,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                childCount: 50))
      ],
    )
```